# Running a game using 3D acceleration in separate virtual terminal slow unless running as root

Tags: gaming, virtual-terminal

I put together a simple script for running Neverwinter Nights from a separate virtual terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -d '' myrcfile <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/game
./nwn
EOF

XINITRC=<(echo "${myrcfile}") xinit -- :1 vt8
```

While this works, gameplay is rather choppy. For reference, it runs fine from the initial / default X instance.

I fiddled around with `schedtool` to see if I could make it any better, and at first it seemed I'd succeeded, but in reality the improvement wasn't because of schedtool but rather because I had [naively] done this:

```
sudo schedtool ${parms} -e ./nwn
^^^^
```

... because some of `schedtool`'s parameters require root (note: `${parms}` is various combinations of `schedtool` parameters).  `schedtool` wasn't responsible for the improvement in speed -- `sudo` was.  To ensure that was the case I replaced the final line of the inner script with `gnome-terminal -c 'sudo ./nwn'` and sure enough it runs flawlessly.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for how to do this?

Here's some of the things I've tried:

- Run X under sudo, then put `su -c ./nwn myusername` in the script
- Ran the game & X as my user, then ran `schedtool` from a separate virtual terminal w/`sudo` to alter the settings for the currently running process but nothing changed

  - This seems to indicate `schedtool` isn't going to do any good

Comment: I'll compromise.  Some of the changes didn't reflect how I wanted it to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.  I added myself to the `video` and `games` group.  I'm not sure which one did it, but it worked.

One oddity I ran into while messing with this: before making the group change I ran glxgears instead; as root it was getting about the same FPS as if I'd ran it from the default session, but as my user it was *reporting* around 500fps.